# Installing PHP-FPM (PHP 5.4) on Ubuntu with NGiNX

Tags: nginx, php5, php-fpm, ubuntu-12.04, pecl

Here is the cmd:

```
pecl install apc
```

Result:

```
downloading APC-3.1.9.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.9.tgz (155,540 bytes)
.................................done: 155,540 bytes
54 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
Cannot find autoconf. Please check your autoconf installation and the
$PHP_AUTOCONF environment variable. Then, rerun this script.

ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

For some reason I cannot install "apc" and "pecl_http".

Also I am using PHP-5.4 and when I compiled it I did:

```
./configure --enable-fpm --with-mcrypt --with-zlib --enable-mbstring --disable-pdo --with-curl --disable-debug --disable-rpath --with-bz2 --with-zlib --enable-sockets --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-mbregex --with-mhash --enable-zip --with-pcre-regex --enable-ctype --enable-bcmath --enable-calendar  --enable-exif  --with-gettext --with-openssl --enable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-wddx --with-xmlrpc
```

I enabled "fpm" is this enough for PHP 5.4 and is it why pecl is not working?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**

I did make && make install

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/lib
Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the package php5-dev: http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/php5-dev

By activating php-fpm during configuration of PHP 5.4 you enable php-fpm: http://php-fpm.org/

Comment: But do I need to install anything else to make PHP-FPM work? Because when I do a search on my server I can't find the "php.ini" file.

Comment: I haven't compiled PHP 5.4 on my own, I usually tend to use Dotdeb packages. On my Debian server the configuration files are located at `/etc/php5/fpm/` but this most certainly differs if you compile it yourself. Consider doing so yourself, because you need the init scripts! Have you tried `find / -name "php.ini"` or `find / -name "php-fpm.conf"`? Or use `locate` (and do `updatedb` before).

Comment: I found it here: /root/src/php-5.4.6/sapi/fpm/php-fpm.conf ...Since I compiled it [PHP] will php5-dev cause problems since I installed it or conflict?

Comment: The php-fpm.conf is found inside the folder of PHP I downloaded... Is it supposed to be there?

Comment: Yes, but only for copying to the right place after you did `make` and `make install`. Have you done that yet? The procedure is always to run the `configure` script at first, then `make` and then `make install`. Sorry if I just asked you something really dumb, but I want to help you.

Comment: Yes I have done the make && make install... No errors if I remember correctly.

Comment: Enter the following in your bash (console): `php --ini`

Comment: I also did use the config first... I posted it in my question. You can see if I mess up somewhere. Yah, yah no problem thanks.

Comment: I also got this two warnings:
configure: WARNING: bison versions supported for regeneration of the Zend/PHP parsers: 1.28 1.35 1.75 1.875 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.4.1 2.4.2 2.4.3 2.5 (found: none).
Second warning: configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.

Comment: I've seen that, but it was missing the `make` and `make install` and after you only found the conf in the directory of your downloaded files it appeared to me like you may have missed those two command. Have you tried `php --ini` yet?

Comment: I am still unsure about something. Should I remove php5-dev?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4574/discussion-between-fleshgrinder-and-jean-nicolas-boulay-desjardins)

Comment: I was able to install PHP5 and all the other stuff... But for some reason I can load the PHP page... Can we continue the chat? Thanks allot!